# The eventual number of generators of modules of which $M$ is a subquotient

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, injective-modules

Let $R$ be a (commutative) ring and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Say that $M$ is *subfinitely generated* if $M$ is a submodule of a finitely-generated module. Write

$$\mathcal F(M) = \{ M \rightarrowtail N \mid N \text{ is fg} \}$$

for the category of finitely-generated modules with $M$ as a submodule (viewed as a full subcategory of the coslice category $Mod(R)_{M/}$). Define

- The *weak rank* of $M$ is the minimal number of generators of a module of which $M$ is a submodule:

$$weakrank(M) = \inf \{ numgen(N) \mid N \in \mathcal F(M)\}$$

- The *eventual rank* of $M$ is the "eventual" minimal number of generators of a module of which $M$ is a submodule:

$$eventualrank(M) = \liminf \{ numgen(N) \mid N \in \mathcal F(M)\}$$

Here, to make sense of the "$\liminf$", we observe that $\mathcal F(M)$ is a filtered category. That is, $eventualrank(M)$ is the minimal $n$ such that, for every $M \subseteq N$ where $N$ is finitely-generated, there is a map $f : N \to N'$ such that $f|_M : M \to N'$ is injective, and $N'$ is generated by $n$ elements.

**Question:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a subfinitely-generated module over $R$. Is $eventualrank(M)$ as defined above necessarily finite?

**Notes:**

- We may equivalently define $weakrank(M)$ to be the minimal $n$ such that $M$ is a subquotient of $R^n$. I believe that $eventualrank(M)$ is then the minimal $n$ such that $R^n$ is cofinal in the category of modules-with-$M$-as-a-subquotient.
- A counterexample would entail having a subfinitely-generated module $M$ (which we may take to be finitely-generated) and monic maps $M \rightarrowtail M_n$ for each $n$ sufficiently large, such that for any map $M_n \to N$ with $f|_M$ monic, $N$ must require at least $n$ elements to generate it (in particular, $M_n$ requires $n$ elements to generate it). We may arrange to have inclusions $M = M_{n_0} \rightarrowtail M_{n_0+1} \rightarrowtail \cdots$ with all the inclusions being essential, and all submodules of the injective hull of $M$.
- I think if I knew more examples of injective hulls I could probably come up with a counterexample, but e.g. every finitely-generated subgroup of $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$ is cyclic, so I don't find a counterexample when $R = \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Just take unitization of $\bigoplus_k k[x]/(x^k)$.

Comment: @DenisT I think you’re suggesting a counterexample. I think you’re saying to let $R$ be the ring with unit associated to the non unital ring you indicated.  I’m not sure what module you have in mind.